# How to get DateTime object in french culture

Tags: c#-4.0, datetime, culture

I am working on an application which have 2 language versions. In this app I am creating a DateTime object for 1st day of the month.
e.g. 
     DateTime startOfMonth = new DateTime(DateTime.Today.Year, DateTime.Today.Month, 1);

The output comes out as;

> 11/1/2013 12:00:00 AM

in english version

However in french version it comes out as 
The culture becomes 'fr-CA' in this case

> 11/1/2013 00:00:00

Can anyone help me in getting value similar to english version ?
With string.Format this can be achieved but **I need DateTime object not string**.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Something like this should work

```
date1.ToString("MM/dd/yy H:mm:ss zzz")
```

Comment: I don't want it to be string, but DateTime object

Comment: in the example code I provided,  date1 is of type System.DateTime.  In order to send to the console or output to the screen, you must create a string representation of the date object.

Answer (score 0):

To custom format your date object, format it with 12 hour time. As you can see in english version it is showing date in 12 hour format and in french version it is showing date in 24 hour format. So format it like:

```
date.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt");
```

or

```
date.ToString("M/d/yyyy h:m:s tt");
```